# Computing $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-analysis

I came across this problem in Fourier analysis, but I'm not sure my confusion is with Fourier analysis per se, it might be that I'm lacking some understanding of sums/series.

I am trying to determine the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}.$$ I know this problem has been posted before, but I want to solve it in a particular way. I already have that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{96}.$$ I found a suggested solution online that said to solve $x = \frac{\pi^4}{96} + \frac{x}{16}$ for $x$ to find the right answer. (So $x$ is the series I am trying to determine.) But I don't understand why I should divide $x$ by $16$. I understand that I have to add something to $\frac{\pi^4}{96},$ since that is the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}$ over all odd indices, but not over the even ones. And I get why I must add $x$ divided by something, but why $16$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** :$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4} +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^4}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^4}=\frac1{2^4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, with what you already have you're already done, since

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n)^4}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)^4}\implies\frac{15}{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)^4}\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

> Although the OP is seeking a way forward through Fourier series analysis, I thought it might be instructive and useful for some users to present an approach that relies on contour integration.  To that end, we proceed.

---

We begin by noting that the function $f(z)=\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{z^4}$ has simple poles at $z=n$, $n\ne 0$ and a fifth-order pole at $z=0$.  The residue at $z=n$, $n\ne 0$ is given by $\frac1{\pi n^4}$.  The residue at $z=0$ is given by $-\frac{\pi^3}{45}$.

Let $C_N$ be the contour $|z|=N+1/2$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to \infty}\oint_{C_N} \frac{\cot(\pi z)}{z^4}\,dz&=2\pi i \left(2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi n^4} +\text{Res}\left(\frac{\cot(\pi z)}{z^4},z=0\right)\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}-\frac{\pi^3}{45}\right)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Hence, we see that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}}$$

And we are done!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> By 'comparing' two well known $\ds{\cot}$-expansions:

\begin{align}
\cot\pars{\pi x} & =
{1 \over \pi x} - {1 \over 3}\,\pi x - {1 \over 45}\,\pars{\pi x}^{3} -
{2 \over 945}\,\pars{\pi x}^{5} + \,\mrm{O}\pars{x^{7}}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{1 \over \pi}{1 \over x} - \pars{\pi \over 3}x -
\pars{\color{#f00}{\pi^{3} \over 45}}x^{3} - \pars{{2\pi^{5} \over 945}}x^{5} + \,\mrm{O}\pars{x^{7}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align} 
\cot\pars{\pi x} & =
{1 \over \pi x} + {2 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{x \over x^{2} - n^{2}} =
{1 \over \pi x} -
{2 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}{x \over 1 - x^{2}/n^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \pi x} -
\pars{{2 \over \pi}\,\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}}x -
\pars{\color{#f00}{{2 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{4}}}}x^{3} + \,\mrm{O}\pars{x^{5}}
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

With \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}:

> $\ds{\color{#f00}{\pi^{3} \over 45} =
> \color{#f00}{{2 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{4}}}\quad
> \implies\bbx{\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{4}} = {\pi^{4} \over 90}}}}$

Answer (score 0):

Sharing ways to do these is always fun, so why not have one more.

We have

$$\sin(z)=z\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z^2}{\pi^2n^2}\right)$$

and

$$\sin(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.$$

Expanding these representations (the sum on the left, the product on the right) gives us

$$z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\cdots=z-\frac{z^3}{\pi^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots\right)+\frac{3z^5}{4\pi^4}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\cdots\right)-\cdots$$

Equating coefficients of like powers gives us

$$\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\;\text{ and }\;\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}.$$